# Routing a service with different access levels

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, routes

Hi I'm creating a project for school and I don't know how to properly route my project. May I borrow your help?

Currently, the project has 3 routers and 3 db users (+ 1 for login):

```js
router.use(/^\/admin/, auth.verifyJWTMiddleWare, adminRouter);
router.use(/^\/user-2/, auth.verifyJWTMiddleWare, user1Router);
router.use(/^\/user-1/, auth.verifyJWTMiddleWare, user2Router);
```

I have 3 users and many services, and taking a example of service "`Service`"

- Admin has access to all routes of `Service`
- User 2 has access to most routes from `Service`
- User 1 has limited access to `Service`

This causes the code to repeat as the users have shared actions.

[image]

But I don't want to create a validation for each route for every user

```js
router.get(/\/anything/, async (req, res)=> {
    if(req.rol === 'user1')
        return res.status(403).end();
    if(req.rol === 'user2')
        return res.status(403).end();

    return res.status(200).send({msg: 'You are the admin'});
});
```

What should I do to get an authenticator to give me the corresponding access according to the user?

[image]

I was thinking in exporting the routes. Something like:

```js
module.exports = {
    admin: [
        route1,
        route2,
        route3,
        route4,
        route5,
        route6
    ],
    user2: [
        route1,
        route2,
        route3,
        route4
    ],
    user1: [
        route1,
        route2
    ],
}
```

But I don't know how to save the route on a variable or even if it's possible, and then, how to use that array. Would it be something like this? Is this secure?

```
const serviceRouter = require('./routers/service');

router.use(/^\/admin/, auth.verifyJWTMiddleWare, serviceRouter.admin);
```

How can I achieve this behavior

Comment: Your last example looks roughly right. Maybe an additional middleware such as `(req, res, next) => req.rol === 'admin' ? next() : res.status(403).end());`, and include this at either the `router.use(/^\/admin/` level or the individual endpoint level.

Comment: But how do I define vars `route1, route2,route3,route4,route5,route6` and... It's correct `router.use(/^\/admin/, auth.verifyJWTMiddleWare, serviceRouter.admin);` ? Wont `serviceRouter.admin` throw an error?

Comment: Yes, something like that should work. Are you able to try it?